# Не могу скрипт правильно настроить на закрытие блока

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/auggszet/
```

сам скрипт

при нажатии кнопки открыть, блок открывается, при повторном нажатии он должен закрыться, а он закроется-откроется

уж и через класс active делал но все равно не получается его правильно сделать
прошу подскажите в чем трабл

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3cszmvy4/

Comment: спасибо
я уж сам сделал, както http://jsfiddle.net/auggszet/5/,
но ваш короче нельзя не признать, буду его юзать

Answer (score 1):

Зачем столько кода , все же решается в 3 строчки

```
$(function() {
   $(this).on("click", "#open_but , #close_but", function() {
       $(this).closest("div#div").find("#cont").stop().slideToggle()
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3cszmvy4/1/

Comment: да вы правы, я плоховато jq знаю
но как в первоначальном примере блок также должен закрыватся при клике в не его

пример пользователя @soledar10 очень коротки но рассчитан на 1 блок на странице а мне надо на несколько

Comment: Посмотрите пример который дал я `https://jsfiddle.net/3cszmvy4/1/` там как раз на любое кол-во блоков

Comment: "но как в моем первоначальном примере блок также должен закрыватся при клике в не его"

пока вот рабочий вариант http://jsfiddle.net/auggszet/5/

Comment: тогда вот так , тоже гораздо короче `https://jsfiddle.net/3cszmvy4/2/` если кликнуть вне блока , то все блоки закрываются

Comment: честно скажу, я почти не понимаю как он работает) 
но при нажатии на контент блок закрывается

спасибо, не заморачивайтесь с темой, ваш пример классный но там несколько недочетов помимо указанного

Answer (score -1):

Готовая версия:

```js
  

$("#open_but").bind( 'click', function( e, display ){
          var parent = $(this).parents('#div'); 
       if ( display == undefined ) { 
           var flag = $(parent).hasClass("active"); 
          } else { 
           var flag = (  display == 'hide' ) ? false : true; 
          }
          
       if ( !flag ) {
        $(parent).addClass('active').find('#cont').fadeIn('fast');
       } else {
        $(parent).removeClass('active').find('#cont').fadeOut('fast');
       }
      });
        
        $("#close_but").click(function(){ $("#open_but").trigger('click', { display: 'hide' } ) })
        
      $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
          if ( $(e.target).attr("id") != 'open_but' ) {
             $("#open_but").trigger('click', { display: 'hide' } ) 
            }
        });
```

```css
div > span,div div,div div span{padding:5px;border:1px solid #444;display:block;}
div div{display:none;}
div:hover,span:hover{border-color:#ddd;}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <span id="open_but">открыть</span>
  <div id="cont">
  контент
  <span id="close_but">закрыть</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: увы но не то, у меня при клике вне главного родителя закрывается блок если открыт

Comment: Ну из-за него у вас он и скрывался - клик учитывался при любом месте, в том числе и при нажатии на кнопку.
http://jsfiddle.net/40gd2r3e/ - c обработкой.

Comment: @Idushii Так какой в какой ссылке правильный ответ в итоге? Пожалуйста, поместите код из ссылки непосредственно в ответ. Ссылки имеют правило отмирать со временем